# Weird error in wxPython, what should I do?

Tags: wxpython

```
(python:6006): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_parent: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET     
(parent)' failed

(python:6006): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_get_direction: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET    
(widget)' failed

Command terminated
```

I'm not sure how to approach this at all. I'm building a front end GUI in wxPython which has been running fine before today. I would post my source code, but it's large and I have no idea where the problem is. If I could get an idea of what this problem means I might be able to find the relevant source. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If it's not causing wxPython to crash, then you probably just have the debug version of wxPython installed. It lets you see stuff like that, but they don't actually hurt anything. At least, that was what I gathered from several conversations about this problem on the wxPython mailing list.

Comment: I would recommend creating a small runnable example that exhibits this issue and post it here and on the wxPython mailing list.